# How to submit form and retrieve data in JSON by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

The normal form of jquery JSON request would through Ajax

```
j.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: url,
   async: true,
   data: urlData,
   timeout: 20000,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(json) {
```

Problem to above solution is even post method still go through and URL. What I am trying to achieve, is that once click a button then the form data is submitted through a JSON call(so that it won't have to be a page submit) and the data return from the call is in JSON format.

So how to achieve the goal?

Comment: Your code seems to be valid, what problem do you have?

Comment: @Vsevolod Goloviznin Thank you. Let's say if there are 20 <input> object in the page, then should I manually put the value of all inputs into `urlData` object, is there a way to use a JSON call but can use some thing like $("#form").submit() to avoid the trouble to put every value(especially when it comes to arrays) into an URL parameter?

Comment: You will do a json call inside your `$("#form").submit()` and will get all data by simply calling `$("#form").serialize()` or `$("#form").serializeArray()`

Comment: @Vsevolod Goloviznin Please forgive me if a silly question, if use $("#form").submit() then I guess the page will submit and browser will load the next(result) page?

Comment: ah... I see the use of e.preventDefault(); how dumb i am..thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault();` to your `submit` event handler so that the default behavior will be prevented.

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop the default action of your submit button, if your using jquery:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
```

If not, `return false;` after ajax call in your click event:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="doTheAjaxCall(); return false;"/>
```